# How to show and hide view in recycler view in Android?

Tags: android

In my app I am using recycler view.I want to show and hide view on particular condition.But when I scroll recycler views I am not getting expected behaviour.When I Visible a view it gets visible for other rows as well randomly.
What I understand is when it recycles it reuses view and when previous view when it gets recycled it finds the visibility of that view.How can I hide view on particular condition? here is my adapter code

```
  @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UrduRhymesViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RhymesModel current = mUrduRhymesList.get(position);
    AppUtility.setCustomFont(mContext, holder.tvUrduRhymesName, Constants.HANDLEE_REGULAR);
    holder.tvUrduRhymesName.setText(current.getRhymeName());
    holder.ivUrduRhymesLogo.setImageUrl(current.getThumbnailUrl(), mImageRequest);
    int status = AppUtility.getFavouriteStatus(mContext, current.getRhymeName(), new UrduRhymesDb(mContext));
    if (status == 0)
        holder.btnFavourite.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_star_unactive);
    else
        holder.btnFavourite.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_star);

    ProgressbarDetails progressbarDetails = ProgressbarDetails.getProgressDetail(current.getRhymeName());
    if (progressbarDetails == null) {
        progressbarDetails = new ProgressbarDetails();
        progressbarDetails.prgProgressBar = holder.pbRhymeDownload;
        progressbarDetails.download_btn_settings = holder.downloadButtonLayout;
    } else {
        progressbarDetails.prgProgressBar = holder.pbRhymeDownload;
        progressbarDetails.download_btn_settings = holder.downloadButtonLayout;
        holder.pbRhymeDownload.setProgress(progressbarDetails.progress);
    }

    ProgressbarDetails.addUpdateProgressDetail(current.getRhymeName(), progressbarDetails);

    if (progressbarDetails != null && progressbarDetails.isDownloading) {
        Log.e("test","downloading foe position "+position );
        holder.downloadButtonLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.btn_download);
        holder.pbRhymeDownload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.pbRhymeDownload.setProgress(progressbarDetails.progress);
    } else {
        Log.e("test","should not be visible for position "+position);
        holder.pbRhymeDownload.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}
```

Here progressbarDetails.isDownloading (having value true) is the criteria when I want to show my view but is else clause it is not hiding my view

Edit: Here ProgressbarDetails (Singleton )is a class keeping reference of every row of adapter's  progress bar.

Comment: what is `progresbarDetails`? please provide full code

Comment: Can you add adapter code?

Comment: One more thing I observed in last else clause when I am checking visibility first using this code

if (holder.pbRhymeDownload.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Log.e("test","visible");
            } else if(holder.pbRhymeDownload.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                Log.e("test","gone");
            }else {
                Log.e("test","no idea");
            }

it says view is gone but in actual device I can see this view visible. What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 4):

No direct way of hiding and unhiding recylerview childitems.

Solution:
Let us assume that the recyclerview adapter is ArrayList
Now make another arraylist (temp_list)

Scenarios:

Hide: iterate through your adapter items and remove the ones that you want to hide. Put each of these into temp_list. After iteration is over, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Show: iterate through your temp_list items and remove the ones that you want to show. Put each of these into adapter. After iteration is over, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

You should add a flag in your viewHolder that indicates if this view should be displayed or not . and check this flag every time in the onBindViewHolder.

because the recyclerView reuses the same views you should make a decision depending on something special for every view in you viewHolder.

Comment: You mean I need to get the row first (on what I need to show my view visible) and then in onBindviewHolder() method I should get tag first then decide what to do...Is that you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

do u mean when your data has been changed?
and your layout want to change ?

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: No, data is not changed I am showing progress of downloading, but when I scroll the recycler view it starts showing progress bar of rest of the rows too.(when I am not downloading it should not be visible for other rows).Initially progressbar is hidden in xml layout file.